# How would I write a C++ function mul_div?

Tags: c++

The functions calls two double argument and should multiply the first double by the second double and return the product in the first. Should also divide the original first double by the original second double and return quotient in the second argument?

I have this so far but not sure if I am on the right lines...

```
void mul_div(double &x, double &y)
{
double mul = x * y;
double div = x / y;
x = mul;
   y = div;
}
```

Comment: This is almost certainly not what you wanted. At the end of your function, you have stored the original values of `x` and `y` in your local variables `div` and `mul` (discarding the intermediate calculation), which then go out of scope and are discarded as well, so your function does effectively nothing. What you probably want is to pass x and y as *references* and then use `x = mul` and `y = prod`

Comment: Think about what is necessary for the caller to see changes in the values that are passed in.  As you wrote it, x and y are copies of the doubles the caller provided, so changes to them will be lost when the function returns.  (Also, if this is an assignment, keep in mind it's a request for a horrible design: in/out parameters, multi-purpose function, etc.  Don't learn to model functions like this.)

Comment: It seems you are under the impression that assignments here set objects to refer to other instances. c++ has value semantics. `mul = prod` will change the value of `mul` to that which `prod` currently holds, and that is the extent of their relationship. It seems that through `prod = x` and `mul = prod` you intend to make all of those `double` refer to the same instance, but that just isn't how c++ works. You will need to familiarize yourself with [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Comment: Have you tried printing the values?  Running in a debugger?  Doing any testing at all?

Answer (score 1):

You're not on the right lines yet.

Although you initialise `mul` to `x * y`, you then overwrite its value with `prod` (which is just `x`). You never actually save `x * y` anywhere.

Aside from that, having `void` as a return type and two parameters of type `double` means there's no way you can actually return the result. You need either parameters of type `double &`, or a return type which can hold two `double` values.

Keep at it though! The attempt you've made so far is not a bad sign, now see if you can understand why it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <iostream>

void mul_div(double &x, double &y)
{
    double mul = x*y;

    double div = x/y;

    x = mul;
    y = div;
}

int main() {
    double x = 1.2, y = 3.6;
    mul_div(x, y);
    std::cout << x << " " << y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why you'd divide `*y` by `*x` rather than the other way around, and then I saw that the OP actually did that too, despite the problem statement requiring the first parameter to be divided by the second. That aside, any particular reason you're using pointers rather than references?

Comment: i simply corrected op's code. i used address as to avoid returning using struct. to return two value you will need to use a struct or array

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri The canonical c++ way of accepting arguments by reference is to use a reference type. In this case `double & x` and `double & y`. In addition, you can return multiple values easily now in c++ using [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or even [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) with [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to extract the results.

Comment: ohh sorry, i thought i was coding in C. my mistake

Comment: still i wanted to avoid any complexity, as op seems a beginner if he is facing problem in this. so it will be better to avoid pairs and tuples

Comment: I say pairs and tuples are much much simpler than pointer. A pair is literally just two stuffs bundle together. With pointer, complications such as null pointer, uninitialized pointer, initialized pointer pointing to uninitialized object, owning or non-owning, dangling pointer, layers of dereferences, shallow copy vs deep copy, etc, etc, easily kick in.

Comment: If you pass by reference, you won't have the common issues associated with pointers.  Remember, a pointer can point to *anywhere* and there is no guarantee that the caller passed in a valid pointer.